# Why are these methods for calculating maximum height inconsistent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The question goes as follows

> A rock is thrown straight up with an initial velocity of $20\ \mathrm{m/s}$. What is the maximum height it will reach?

I came up with two possible answers, $D = 20.4\ \text{meters}$ or $D = 61.2\ \text{meters}$.

The first answer resulted from using the equation:

$$X_f = X_i +  (V_f^2 - V_i^2/2a)$$

The second answer resulted from using these equations:

$$\begin{align}
t &= V_f - V_i/a &
X_f &= X_i + V_i T + (at^2/2)
\end{align}$$

Why do I have an inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for t is correct, but in the second equation you added, instead of subtracted, the acceleration. Remember, gravity is a downward acceleration. Simple arithmetic error.